# Android implement Audio echo cancellation for all android mobile phones programmatically

Tags: android

I am working on the android video conference application. for that we are using `AudioRecord` for recording and get  the buffer from the AudioRecord using

```
"read(buffer,readBufferSize, size - readBufferSize);"
```

For playing audio we are using `AudioTrack`. while playing and recording we are getting our self `echo`.

**How to remove this Echo programmatically.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be setting the source as [VOICE_COMMUNICATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_COMMUNICATION). This setting should enable Android to use its internal AEC. If you need to support multiple devices and Android versions then test the AEC results on several devices and Android versions since results might not be the same across the board. You can also take a look at this blog [post](http://solicall.com/echo-cancellation-on-android-and-audiorecord/)

Comment: Thanks Tim for the reply. I already used the same VOICE_COMMUNICATION. but it is not work in all android devices.    How to implement echo cancellation software?

Comment: There are open source free echo cancellation software packages (e.g. Speex) and commercial echo cancellation software packages  (e.g. SoliCall). To start with, you can google for "speex for android".